# Executing queries from Intellij Ultimate DB plugin to AWS Timestream service

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-timestream

I am trying to use Intellij Idea to query AWS timestream however I am having some problems with it.

when I execute the query in AWS console it works just fine, executing the same query in

Intellij Idea return an error:

```
Error executing query with id "null": Requested database 'data-test' not found for identifier 'data-test.table-name' at line 1:15 (Service: AmazonTimestreamQuery; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: req-id; Proxy: null) com.tsshaded.amazonaws.services.timestreamquery.model.ValidationException: Requested database 'data-test' not found for identifier 'data-test.table-name' at line 1:15 (Service: AmazonTimestreamQuery; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: req-id; Proxy: null)
```

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM "data-test"."table-name" LIMIT 10
```

I am using the latest driver amazon-timestream-jdbc-1.0.2-shaded.jar

Comment: Have you tried to execute without quotes? E.g.: `SELECT * FROM data-test.table-name LIMIT 10`?

Comment: Can you please share the steps you took to set up Timestream in Intellij?